# Inconsistency between scores?

Tags: support

I was having a look to my MATLAB tag scores, and I realize there is a big difference between the scores shown in the "track next tag" in my profile and the score shown in the tag "top users".

The description of the tags say that you need 1000 score in the tag (in answers).  In the top users tag, the section I refer to is also supposed to be just answers. Why is there such a big difference?

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Sayse thanks, I couldnt find it. Unfortunatedly, that doenst solve anything, just links to someone that also had the problem :(

Comment: The answer is that it doesn't update so its value is at whatever it was when you selected the tag, you can manually update it by retracking the badge

Comment: @Sayse Still a bug :(. Closed the question as duped! And I made all the efforts making hand-drawn red circles.......